# What did I do wrong proving derivative of $y = \sec(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I wanted to prove for myself, using chain rule instead of quotient rule, that $\sec'(x)$ is $\sec(x)\tan(x)$ but I got $\tan(x)$. That's how I did it:
\begin{align*}
\sec(x) = 1/\cos(x) & \Rightarrow y = \frac{1}{\cos(x)} = \cos(x)^{-1}\\\\
& \Rightarrow y' = \frac{-1}{\cos(x)}(-\sin(x)) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \tan(x)
\end{align*}

What did I do wrong?

If you are wondering how did I get that result, first I took derivative of the outward funcion lets say $y = u^{-1}$ than I took derivative of it so $(-1)uu'$, where $u'$ is derivative of the function so in my case $\cos(x)$ which is $-\sin(x)$.

Comment: You didn't subtract one off the power $$y' = -1 \cdot (-\sin(x)) \cdot \cos(x)^{- \color{red}{2}}$$ Note that $$y(x) = 1/u(x) \implies y' = -1 u'(x) u^{- \color{red}{2}}$$

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset mathematics. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $$(u^{-1})'=-u^{-2}u'$$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sure will. Thanks for making my question tidier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to reduce $1$ in the power of the fraction.

You can simply solve for the derivative by doing:
$$\begin{align*}
  y & = \sec{(x)}\\
  \frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}x}y & = \frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{\cos{(x)}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Now consider $u = \cos(x)$, then the equation becomes, using the chain rule:
$$\begin{align*}
  y' & = \left(\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}u}\frac{1}{u}\right)\cdot u'\\
  & = \left(\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}u} u^{-1}\right)\cdot u'\\
  & = -u^{-2}\cdot u'\\
  & = -\frac{1}{u^2}\cdot u'\\
  & = -\frac{-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)\cos(x)}\\
  & = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}
\end{align*}$$
$$\boxed{y' = \sec(x)\cdot\tan(x)}$$

Hopefully you can spot the reduction.

Comment: Thanks. That helped thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that $$\biggl(\frac1u\biggr)'=-\frac1{u^2}\cdot u',$$
and more generally that
$$\biggl(\frac1{u^n}\biggr)'=-\frac n{u^{n+1}}\cdot u'.$$